# What is the best way to create Flat Files for each row in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I just wrote about a script that would allow me to create an XML file based on a query. I got it fixed and now the script seen below can be used to create an XML string for a given record (notice the 'where' clause in the outer-most query:

```
declare @body nvarchar(max) =
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Mapi 
destination_reference="ABC06EMP" name="WorkOrder" source_reference="ABC999" 
xmlns="http://www.company.com/Mapi/WorkOrder" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' +
cast((
select 'ABC999' as SourceTradingPartner,
     'ABC06EMP' as DestinationTradingPartner,
     right('                    ' + 'E_' + cast(WorkOrderHeader.EmpNumber as varchar), 20) as WorkOrder,
     WorkOrderHeader.Name as WorkOrderDescription,
     'OPR' as ResponsiblePersonID,
     'USA' as DivisionID,
     'A' as SynchIndicatorID
    , (
    select '0001' as WorkOrderLineReference,
             'CONSIGN' as Item,
             '2018-03-09' as RequiredManufacturingStartDate,
             '2018-03-09' as OpenDate,
             '2018-03-09' as DueDate,
             '1' as OrderQty,
             'W' as RoutingUsedFlag,
             'I' as BillOfMaterialUsedFlag,
             'B' as ScheduleID,
             '3' as QAStatusID,
             'CNSG' as AccountingGroupCode,
             'R' as StateCode,
             '134800' as DueTime,
             '144846' as OpenTime,
             '134800' as RequiredManufacturingStartTime,
             '2' as InventoryStatus,
             'A' as SynchIndicatorID,
             'Y' as SubstitutePriorityMethod
        , (
        select 'A' as SynchIndicatorID,
                 '10' as Increment
            ,(
            select 'A' as SynchIndicatorID,
                     '  10' as Operation,
                     'CONSIGN' as [Function],
                     'I' AS OperationType,
                     rtrim(isnull(WorkOrderRouting.WorkCenter, '')) as WorkCenter
                , (
                select 'A' as SynchIndicatorID,
                         right('    ' + cast(row_number() over (partition by WorkOrderRoutingTool.Employee
                                                                             order by WorkOrderRoutingTool.id desc, WorkOrderRoutingTool.PartNumber)
                                                    as varchar), 4) as ToolSeq,
                         WorkOrderRoutingTool.PartNumber as ToolID,
                         cast(WorkOrderRoutingTool.Qty as varchar) as ToolQuantity
                from ZLS_CONSIGN WorkOrderRoutingTool with (nolock)
                where WorkOrderRoutingTool.Employee = WorkOrderHeader.OID
                for xml auto, elements, type
                )
            from Employees WorkOrderRouting with (nolock)
            where WorkOrderRouting.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID
            for xml auto, elements, type
            )
            ,(
            select 'A' as SynchIndicatorID
            from Employees WorkOrderRoutingAddendum with (nolock)
            where WorkOrderRoutingAddendum.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID
            for xml auto, elements, type
            )
        from Employees WorkOrderRoutingHeader with (nolock)
        where WorkOrderRoutingHeader.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID
        for xml auto, elements, type
        )
    from Employees WorkOrderLine with (nolock)
    where WorkOrderLine.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID
    for xml auto, elements, type
    )
    ,(
    select 'A' as SynchIndicatorID,
             '4' as PlanningStatus,
             '2' as ManufacturingStatus
    from Employees WorkOrderLineAddendum with (nolock)
    where WorkOrderLineAddendum.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID
    for xml auto, elements, type
    )
from Employees WorkOrderHeader with (nolock)
where WorkOrderHeader.EmpNumber = 10171
order by WorkOrderHeader.EmpNumber
for xml auto, elements, type
) as nvarchar(max)) +
N'</Mapi>';
select @body as COL_XML;
```

Using this query in SSMS works fine and I can get the XML code with the proper tags. I;ve used this and saved it as an XML file, tested it and my system loads it with no problems.

Now, I need my process to create the XML file for me. To do this, I'm using Visual Studio's Integration Services Project like this:

!(https://ibb.co/eBBpSx)

As you can see, the OLE DB Source block has the SQL script I used above, then I'm converting the output to DT_TEXT and using the code page 65001 (UTF-8), and finally, using a Flat File Destination. But this last one has a static file name, and I need to create the file based on each record in the table.

So I have to remove the 'where' clause in my script and let this run for all employees, and create an XML file per each employee record. Not sure if I can still use the SSIS package to do this, or not. I was testing the use of the bcp SQL command but I'm on SQL Server v2008 and I was reading it has some limitations when it comes to create files in a specific format.

How could I create the multiple XML files per each employee record?

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

UPDATE 1: This is the code I've been trying to use with bcp but it's giving me all sort of errors.

```
declare @fileName varchar(max)
declare @sqlStr varchar(max)
declare @sqlCmd varchar(8000)

set @fileName = 'C:\Temp\saved.xml'

SET @sqlStr = 'declare @body nvarchar(max) = ' +
              '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Mapi destination_reference="ABC06EMP" name="WorkOrder" source_reference="ABC999" xmlns="http://www.company.com/gapi/WorkOrder" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">''' +
              'cast((' +
              'select ''ABC999'' as SourceTradingPartner, ' +
              '''ABC06EMP'' as DestinationTradingPartner, ' +
              'right(''                    '' + ''E_'' + cast(WorkOrderHeader.EmpNumber as varchar), 20) as WorkOrder, ' +
              'WorkOrderHeader.Name as WorkOrderDescription, ' +
              '''OPR'' as ResponsiblePersonID, ' +
              '''USA'' as DivisionID, ' +
              '''A'' as SynchIndicatorID' +
              ', (' +
              'select ''0001'' as WorkOrderLineReference, ' +
              '''CONSIGN'' as Item, ' +
              '''2018-03-09'' as RequiredManufacturingStartDate, ' +
              '''2018-03-09'' as OpenDate, ' +
              '''2018-03-09'' as DueDate, ' +
              '''1'' as OrderQty, ' +
              '''W'' as RoutingUsedFlag, ' +
              '''I'' as BillOfMaterialUsedFlag, ' +
              '''B'' as ScheduleID, ' +
              '''3'' as QAStatusID, ' +
              '''CNSG'' as AccountingGroupCode, ' +
              '''R'' as StateCode, ' +
              '''134800'' as DueTime, ' +
              '''144846'' as OpenTime, ' +
              '''134800'' as RequiredManufacturingStartTime, ' +
              '''2'' as InventoryStatus, ' +
              '''A'' as SynchIndicatorID, ' +
              '''Y'' as SubstitutePriorityMethod' +
              ', (' +
              'select ''A'' as SynchIndicatorID, ' +
              '''10'' as Increment' +
              ',(' +
              'select ''A'' as SynchIndicatorID, ' +
              '''  10'' as Operation, ' +
              '''CONSIGN'' as [Function], ' +
              '''I'' AS OperationType, ' +
              'rtrim(isnull(WorkOrderRouting.WorkCenter, '''')) as WorkCenter' +
              ', (' +
              'select ''A'' as SynchIndicatorID, ' +
              'right(''    '' + cast(row_number() over (partition by WorkOrderRoutingTool.Employee ' +
              'order by WorkOrderRoutingTool.id desc, WorkOrderRoutingTool.PartNumber) ' +
              'as varchar), 4) as ToolSeq, ' +
              'WorkOrderRoutingTool.PartNumber as ToolID, ' +
              'cast(WorkOrderRoutingTool.Qty as varchar) as ToolQuantity ' +
              'from ZLS_CONSIGNACION WorkOrderRoutingTool with (nolock) ' +
              'where WorkOrderRoutingTool.Employee = WorkOrderHeader.OID ' +
              'for xml auto, elements, type' +
              ') ' +
              'from Employees WorkOrderRouting with (nolock) '+
              'where WorkOrderRouting.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID ' +
              'for xml auto, elements, type' +
              ')' +
              ', (' +
              'select ''A'' as SynchIndicatorID ' +
              'from Employees WorkOrderRoutingAddendum with (nolock) ' +
              'where WorkOrderRoutingAddendum.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID ' +
              'for xml auto, elements, type' +
              ') ' +
              'from Employees WorkOrderRoutingHeader with (nolock) ' +
              'where WorkOrderRoutingHeader.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID ' +
              'for xml auto, elements, type' +
              ') ' +
              'from Employees WorkOrderLine with (nolock) ' +
              'where WorkOrderLine.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID ' +
              'for xml auto, elements, type' +
              ')' +
              ', (' +
              'select ''A'' as SynchIndicatorID, ' +
              '''4'' as PlanningStatus, ' +
              '''2'' as ManufacturingStatus ' +
              'from Employees WorkOrderLineAddendum with (nolock) ' +
              'where WorkOrderLineAddendum.OID = WorkOrderHeader.OID ' +
              'for xml auto, elements, type' +
              ') ' +
              'from Employees WorkOrderHeader with (nolock) ' +
              'where WorkOrderHeader.EmpNumber = 10171 ' +
              'order by WorkOrderHeader.EmpNumber ' +
              'for xml auto, elements, type' +
              ') as nvarchar(max)) + ' +
              '''</Mapi>''; ' +
              'select @body as COL_XML;'

set @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'

exec xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

---

UPDATE 2: I'm trying to follow these instructions when it comes to create the individual files for each record:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

But when I try to use this code:

```
select 'SHV999' as SourceTradingPartner,
     'SHV06EMP' as DestinationTradingPartner,
     right('                    ' + 'E_' + cast(t.EmpNumber as varchar), 20) as WorkOrder,
...
from Employees t with (nolock)
where t.EmpNumber = ?
order by t.EmpNumber
for xml path('WorkOrderHeader'), type
```

I get an error (please note I've replaced the static old value 10171 for a parameter ?):
'There is a data source column with no name'

So I tried to name the XML column as follows:

```
select (
select 'SHV999' as SourceTradingPartner,
     'SHV06EMP' as DestinationTradingPartner,
     right('                    ' + 'E_' + cast(t.EmpNumber as varchar), 20) as WorkOrder,
...
from Employees t with (nolock)
where t.EmpNumber = ?
order by t.EmpNumber
for xml path('WorkOrderHeader'), type
) as COL_XML
```

But now I get a different error:
"Syntax error, permission violation or other nonspecific error".

I can't find a way to make this work by trying to add a parameter in the SQL query, and name the column at the same time.

Any ideas would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a foreach loop?

Comment: I'd use a `CURSOR` and create one `BCP` statement for each row dynamically and fire this with `EXEC`. But I doubt, that this would create real `utf-8`. Most recommended is to place `utf-16` and send it out with option `-w`. With SSIS I don't know...

Comment: Snugo: glad to see your comment again. I've tried to use the bcp approach but I'm having trouble trying to put the right code there. I was thinking about the cursor but I was under the impression that the SSIS package might be a bit faster. at any rate, I'd like to try them both and see which works better.
when trying to write the bcp, I'm getting errors. I'll post the code so you can see it.

Comment: Tab: I'm not that well experienced in SSIS; have never used foreach loop. not sure how to make it work for each record in the table. if you could provide some example or guide me to a web page that would be awesome (I'm already investigating this option). thx

Comment: Solid tutorial on ForEach loop: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

Comment: Greenspark: I'm trying to follow that tutorial but I'm having trouble when I try to use my SQL code and add a parameter in there. I'm getting a weird error that says "an OLED DB record is provided. Description: syntax error, permission violation or other nonspecific error". I'm pretty sure it's related to the fact that I'm trying to use a parameter in that query code... Not sure how to make that work though...